# Installing netbeans in ubuntu 15

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

After installing Netbeans 8.0.2 in ubuntu 15, it fails to load past the splash screen saying ("loading modules"). I have tried reinstalling it and even using different JDKs. Could someone advise me on how to solve this?

Comment: Depends on how did u install netbeans. If it just unzipped archive then there is a netbeans.sh (or just executable netbeans) launcher. Run netbeans in console mode and get error stacktrace a publish in here.

Comment: If u used package manager open terminal and run netbeans command and get stack trace

Comment: As well look into NETBEANS_HOME/nb/var/log/messages.log. There must be something cause an error